# How to make a function that returns a value when a corresponding variable is inputted?

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a function that would return me the value "1" when I input "apple"

```
data <- data.frame(number = c(1,
                              2,
                              3),
                   fruit = c("apple",
                             "banana",
                             "orange"))
```

I'm sure it's really easy, but I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `subset`

```
unlist(subset(data, fruit == "apple", select = 'number'), use.names = FALSE)
#[1] 1
```

Or with `[`

```
data$number[data$fruit == "apple"]
```

---

It can be wrapped as a function

```
f1 <- function(dat, colNm1, colNm2, stringVal) {
         dat[[colNm2]][dat[[colNm1 == stringVal]
   }

f1(data, "fruit", "number", "apple")
```